# Exception in Rxjava in chained call android (RxJavaAssemblyException: assembled)

Tags: android, rx-java, chaining

I'm trying to do a call in RxJava. I may be doing too many chains in the call.  There are so many Observables and transformations that I am afraid the assembly is lost. Unfortunately, I need to use these functions.    I have a method here that I am calling in my fragment. The method never gets called when I'm debugging and set a break point.

In my Fragment I am calling offlineItems() here:

```
private fun streamDownloads(): Observable<Unit> {

  return downloadsDataRepository.offlineItems()
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .map { downloadLoaded(it) } // Exception here.  
}
```

The downloadLoaded(it) is not called and sometimes it returns an exception.  I;m concerned that I map have too complicated a chained call in my RxJava.  Here is the offlineItems() call.

```
fun offlineItems(): Observable<List<MediaItem>> {

  val list = getAllMyDownloadedMediaItems()
  return list.flatMapIterable { it }
    .flatMap { mediaStore.getMediaItemWithId(MediaId(it.request.id)) } // this method is called . 
    .toList()                                                          // returns an Observable<MediaItem>
    .toObservable()
 }
```

Just to be thorough, the mediaStoreCall is:

```
override fun getMediaItemWithId(mediaId: MediaId): Observable<MediaItem> {
    return if (isOnline()) {
      Observable.just(Unit)
        .effectMap { fetchAndStoreRemote(mediaId) }
        .flatMap { mediaItemFromDB(mediaId) }
    } else {
      mediaItemFromDB(mediaId)
    }
  }
```

The list I am getting (downloads from exoplayer):

```
fun getAllMyDownloadedMediaItems(): Observable<List<Download>> {
    return Observable.just(downloadManager.downloadIndex.getDownloads(Download.STATE_COMPLETED).use { index ->
      mutableListOf<Download>().apply {
        if (index.isFirst || index.moveToFirst()) {
          do {
            add(index.download)
          } while (index.moveToNext())
       }
      }
    })
  }
```

Downloaded method in the fragment called from the above method:

```
private fun downloadLoaded(downloads: List<MediaItem>) {
  if (downloads.isEmpty()) {
    downloadStateView.setState(StateView.State.EMPTY)
  } else {
    downloadStateView.setState(StateView.State.CONTENT)
    episodeAdapter.items = listOf(Header(downloads.size)) + downloads.map(::Item)
  }
}
```

I'm calling the streamDownloads in onResume of the fragment.

```
override fun onResume() {
  super.onResume()
  Observable.merge(
    streamDownloads(),
    handleEmptyAction()
  ).autoDispose(this)
   .subscribe()
 }
```

I'm by no means an RxJava expert, so if someone could point me to what I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT**
Stacktrace:

```
RxJavaAssemblyException: assembled
at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at io.reactivex.Observable.map(Observable.java:9781)
at DownloadsFragment.streamDownloads(DownloadsFragment.kt:143)
at DownloadsFragment.onResume(DownloadsFragment.kt:128)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2649)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState
at  FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState
at  FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
at  FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2659)
at  FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2625)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2658)
at FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:922)
at FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState
at FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
at FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1884)
at FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute
at FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
at FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
at RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Are you using RxJavaAssemblyTracking from RxJavaExtensions? If so, how does the StackTrace look like without AssemblyTracking?

Comment: @HansWurst yes, I am.  Without it, I get no stacktrace at all.

Comment: is this the full stack-trace? I am missing subscribeActual stackframes. I try to reproduce it, but so far I did not have much luck in that. Whe you disable Assembly-Tracking, don't you get a OnErrorNotImplementException in the subscribe in the method onResume(), or does it just fail silently?

Comment: @HansWurst just fails silently.  I also only occasionally get the stack trace, and that I found by debugging.  Nothing in Logcat or Debug console.

Comment: method offlineItems you should put all your code into chain instead of call like that. make return Observable.fromCallable { getAllMyDownloadedMediaItems() }. flatMapIterable ...

Comment: @HansWurst I have a bounty on this question.

Comment: I tried, but I could not reproduce it. There is probably no chance to get the source-code to reproduce it?